# Android EditText onKeyUp

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyup

Just started with android, want to figure out keyUp on edittext. I followed various tutorials on keyUp it works but only on pressing back button. I want it to work on type. Just like phonebook, as you type some event will be triggered.

My code:

```
    private EditText input;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
        addKeyListener();
    }

    public void addKeyListener() {
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.names);
        input.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(Contacts.this,
                        input.getText() + " you have typed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return true;

            }
        });

    }
```

Current code is only working on back button, if I press back button then the `Toast` comes.

Comment: You should have a lot at the [TextWatcher.class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
import android.text.TextWatcher;
```

.
.

You can add a TextWatcher to your text field. In your case, this would 
look something like:

```
  EditText in = new EditText(this); 
  in.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int s, int b, int c) { 
      Log.i("Key:", cs.toString()); 
    } 
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { } 
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int i, int j, int 
k) { } 
  });
```

Best,

Answer (score 2):

**Chack if user type on EditText, and onTextChanged you can use your trigger :)
Hope its help:)**

```
    EditText mTextPhoneNumber;

    mTextPhoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.example);

        mTextPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                              Log.d("LOGER" , s.length()+""); // show the count of the Text in the TextView                        

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                            }


});
```